# If I have multiple OR conditions in a SQL query that checks column values, how can I return the columns that met the condtion?

Tags: sql

Let's say I want to check 10 different columns to see if they contain the word "tokyo".

```
  Goods_Services_String LIKE '%tokyo%' OR 
  Input_Materials_String LIKE '%tokyo%' OR 
  Property_Plant_Equipment_String LIKE '%tokyo%' OR 
  Production_Process_String LIKE '%tokyo%' OR 
  Capital_Expenditures_String LIKE '%tokyo%' OR 
  Employee_Locations_String LIKE '%tokyo%' OR 
  Contractors_Locations_String LIKE '%tokyo%' OR 
  Research_And_Development_Desc_String LIKE '%tokyo%' OR 
  Distribution_String LIKE '%tokyo%' OR 
  Sales_And_Marketing_Desc_String LIKE '%tokyo%'
```

But rather than just returning the row that meets this condition, I would also like to know which of the columns met this condition. Is this possible?

Comment: you need to add a case when for all tthe query, also concatenate all fields and compare it to the search term so you have only one condition

Comment: What if there are two matches?

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: If this is a common use case for you, you might want to consider a different/additional database structure that puts all those values into one column, with a separate column to tell you which kind of value it is.

Comment: @SalmanA I am using pyobc

Answer (score 2):

I would use a lateral join for this. E.g. in SQL server you would:

```
select *
from t
cross apply (values
    ('col 1', col1),
    ('col 2', col2)
) as columns(name, value)
where value like '%tokyo%'
```

It is a set based approach; the performance won't be good but using several `or ... like` isn't optimal either.

Comment: I do not htink that would work because the query can different for each column so it could be "like tokyo" or another one could be ">1000000"

Answer (score 1):

The CASE statement is SQL's way of handling if/then logic. The CASE statement is followed by at least one pair of WHEN and THEN statements
Your SQL query will be like Something like this:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN Goods_Services_String LIKE '%tokyo%' THEN 'Goods_Services_String'
         WHEN Input_Materials_String LIKE '%tokyo%' THEN 'Input_Materials_String'
         WHEN Property_Plant_Equipment_String LIKE '%tokyo%' THEN 'Property_Plant_Equipment_String'
         WHEN Production_Process_String LIKE '%tokyo%' THEN 'Production_Process_String'
         WHEN Capital_Expenditures_String LIKE '%tokyo%' THEN 'Capital_Expenditures_String'
         WHEN Employee_Locations_String LIKE '%tokyo%' THEN 'Employee_Locations_String'
         WHEN Contractors_Locations_String LIKE '%tokyo%' THEN 'Contractors_Locations_String'
         WHEN Research_And_Development_Desc_String LIKE '%tokyo%' THEN 'Research_And_Development_Desc_String'
         WHEN Distribution_String LIKE '%tokyo%' THEN 'Distribution_String'
         WHEN Sales_And_Marketing_Desc_String LIKE '%tokyo%' THEN 'Sales_And_Marketing_Desc_String'
      ELSE NULL END AS 'tokyo was here!'
   FROM YourTableName
       WHERE Goods_Services_String LIKE '%tokyo%' OR 
             Input_Materials_String LIKE '%tokyo%' OR 
             Property_Plant_Equipment_String LIKE '%tokyo%' OR 
             Production_Process_String LIKE '%tokyo%' OR 
             Capital_Expenditures_String LIKE '%tokyo%' OR 
             Employee_Locations_String LIKE '%tokyo%' OR 
             Contractors_Locations_String LIKE '%tokyo%' OR 
             Research_And_Development_Desc_String LIKE '%tokyo%' OR 
             Distribution_String LIKE '%tokyo%' OR 
             Sales_And_Marketing_Desc_String LIKE '%tokyo%';
```

Comment: If there are multiple matches, simply change the logic to `concat_ws('; ', case when foo like ... then 'foo' end, case when bar like ... then 'bar' end, ...)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).